# Segue textfields to a string array

Tags: arrays, swift, segue

I'm doing an app using swift that takes the entries in 6 text fields and passes them through a segue into an empty string array on a second view controller. How do I do that?

This is my code, is the basics, but I'm not sure how I can send the information through.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! secondView

    if segue.identifier == segueID {

        destination.stringArray = ?

    }

}
```

The array on my second view controller is this:

```
var stringArray = [String]()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest way:

```
destination.stringArray = view.subviews.flatMap { ($0 as? UITextField)?.text }
```

Comment: The asker didn't necessarily say that all textfields in the view were to be used. This also doesn't account for textfields more than 1 level down the view hierarchy (ie. being contained in a subview).

Comment: Of course it needs to be rewritten in case there are more levels of hierarchy. That's a very good point :)
My answer is showing how to achieve it in a short way when all textfields are subviews of one root view.

Comment: Actually this one worked like a charm. Sorry I wasn't very specific in my question. All text fields need to be used, or an alert will show preventing the segue from occurring. Thank you very much for this one. Simple and straight to the point. :)

Comment: @VeronicaG Possibly you know this already, but note that for empty textfields, no entry will be included using the solution above (so for the case where all textfields are empty, `stringArray` will be an empty array).

Comment: @dfri It's ok, I used a UIAlert to prevent the user from leaving the textfields empty.

Answer (score 1):

Are your 6 textfields in an `IBOutletCollection` (in other words, an array of textfields) or are they each their own `IBOutlet` (textfield)? Either way, your question comes down to putting all of their text values in an array, which can be done like this if they're in an `IBOutletCollection`:

```
destination.stringArray = myTextFieldCollection.flatMap { $0.text }
```

Or, if they're not in an array:

```
destination.stringArray = [myTextField1, myTextField2, ...,
    myTextField6].flatMap { $0.text }
```

I'm using `flatMap` in these because `UITextField.text` is an optional `String?`, so they need to be unwrapped to `String`, which `flatMap` safely does.

Comment: Note that the latter will not work as the `stringArray` in destionation does not allow optional `String` entries.

Comment: Good catch, fixed.